# Migrating users to Google Identity Platform with pbkdf2_sha512

Tags: hash, firebase-authentication, passwords, flask-security, google-identity

I'm migrating user authentication for a Flask app from Flask Security to Google Identity Platform (GIP).  GIP includes a process for migrating users by providing password hashes and the details of the hashing algorithm as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/migrating-users).

My issue is that my Flask app has been using `pbkdf2_sha512` to hash passwords but GIP migration doesn't include this as an option (see above link).  GIP has `pbkdf2_sha256` and many other options so I'm surprised to not see `pbkdf2_sha512` as an option as well.

Is there a way to make this work or will I need to ask all my users to create new accounts?

If not, why wouldn't Google support `pbkdf2_sha512`?!?

Comment: Hey @gaefan, did you find out a way to migrate users? I wanted to migrate to google firebase auth, but I have the same problem, pbkdf2_sha512 is not listed [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users)

Comment: @mtb, nope. I ended up having all my users recreate accounts and reconfirm their email address. :(